# Regex Extract but exclude random number bit

Tags: php, regex, drupal

Regex parsing problem, I am putting together an embed video provider module for Drupal.

For basic video pages the url is like this: http://v.ku6.com/show/EJEiKXHN1avFezNi.html so this regex works fine to parse the video code:
'@v.ku6.com/show/([^"\&/]+).html@i',

But many pages use this pattern http://v.ku6.com/special/show_4086312/ZP0DCEnRVpK4BiEU.html so I need to extract "ZP0DCEnRVpK4BiEU" but exclude the random 4086312 numbers there.

here's the regex stuff I have so far: 
'@v.ku6.com/special/show_[what goes here?]/([^"\&/]+).html@i',

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@v.ku6.com/special/show(?:_\d+)?/([^"\&/]+).html@i
```

the `(?:)` is a non capturing group, the `?` afterwards says it can be there or not and the `\d+` is at least one number

Answer (score 2):

`what goes here?`: `\d+` (digits)